# How to trigger an event before another one on a same element using native JS?

Tags: javascript, events

I've a problem with `eventListener`. 
In my case i use an external library (jquery.jstree-pre1.0fix2) that trigger a `blur` event on an input.

I do the same but i need that my event is triggered before the one from the library. I found some solution but they were all using jQuery.

Do you have any idea or code example with native JS that can help me to trigger my event before the event from the library ?

Below is the event i want to do before the one of the library :

```
document.getElementById('treeView').addEventListener("change", function (ev) {
    if(ev.target.classList.contains('jstree-rename-input')) {
        var inputRename = ev.target;
        inputRename.addEventListener("blur", function(eve) {
            eve.value = encodeURI(eve.value);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Paste your code along with the library or minimal reproducible example using codepen or jsfiddle, that will help identify the requirement. Also have you tried anything looking on google ?

Comment: Can you add your eventListener before th library is requested?

Comment: @mplungjan that's what i'm trying to do

Comment: @SatyamPathak i added the code of my event and the name of the lib

Comment: Can you add **your** SCRIPT before you add the script tags of the library is what I meant

Comment: @mplungjan It's not possible

Comment: And if you use on("input")  instead ?

Comment: @mplungjan Already tested, but it doesn't work either :(

Comment: Then use setInterval to monitor the field

Comment: How should i use setInterval in my case  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot make sure your code is before the jstree, then you can try the following - not recommended but should do the job

```
const tId = setInterval(function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('jstree-rename-input')].forEach(
    inp => inp.value=encodeURI(decodeURI(inp).value)) // make sure we do not double encode
  );
},300)
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it seem it doesn't work for me

Comment: Impossible to guess without seeing your code in action